# Unable to assign value in a variable after Substring | Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Something weird happening here, or I couldn't figure out myself.

I am unable to assign value from one variable to other. What I am doing is, retrieving **filename** and then **substring** it to check the last 6 letters which is the ***creation date(yymmdd)*** of that file, needed for further processing.
I have listed 2 different debugging version, which is retriving the filename, but some problem is happening during substring and assigning it to another variable.

- Although during basename itself, it's doing perfect with substring (go to ***Debugging Version 2***)

**Debugging version 1:**

**Code:**

```
fname=''
fdate=''
for file in /home/fimsctl/datafiles/outbound/timelog/timelog_file_*.csv ; do

    echo "Debugging Test: 123"

    fname=` basename $file `

    echo "Debugging Test: 456"

    echo "$fname"

    echo "Debugging Test: 789"

    fdate=` $fname | cut -c2-4 `

    echo "Debugging Test: abc"

    echo "$fdate"

    echo "Debugging Test: def"

  done
```

**Output:**

```
Debugging Test: 123
Debugging Test: 456
timelog_file_150112.csv
Debugging Test: 789
testb.ksh[119]: timelog_file_150112.csv:  not found
Debugging Test: abc

Debugging Test: def
```

**Debugging version 2:**

**Code:**

```
fname=''
fdate=''
for file in /home/fimsctl/datafiles/outbound/timelog/timelog_file_*.csv ; do

    echo "Debugging Test: 123"

    fname=` ( basename $file ) | cut -c14-19 `

    echo "Debugging Test: 456"

    echo "$fname"

    echo "Debugging Test: 789"

    fdate=` $fname | cut -c2-4 `

    echo "Debugging Test: abc"

    echo "$fdate"

    echo "Debugging Test: def"

  done
```

**Output:**

```
Debugging Test: 123
Debugging Test: 456
150112
Debugging Test: 789
testb.ksh[119]: 150112:  not found
Debugging Test: abc

Debugging Test: def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
fdate=` $fname | cut -c2-4 `
```

It should be:

```
fdate=`echo "$fname" | cut -c2-4`
```

Comment: My poor. Thanks... All set :-) Had been stuck on this for like last 40 minutes. Huh...

Comment: Could you please help me in this too. Link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900170/how-to-sort-integer-array-in-ksh-unix-shell-scripting