# How to sort Integer Array in ksh | Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, ksh

How to sort integer array in KornShell.
Found this link, [KornShell Sort Array of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198283/kornshell-sort-array-of-integers) but it seems to be not working and throwing error.

Code:

```
NUM_ARR[1]=-1
NUM_ARR[2]=-2
NUM_ARR[3]=-3
NUM_ARR[4]=-4
NUM_ARR[5]=-5
NUM_ARR[6]=-6
NUM_ARR[7]=-7
for file in /home/fimsctl/datafiles/outbound/timelog/timelog_file_*.csv ; do

    SORTED_NUM_ARR=`($(printf "%s\n" ${NUM_ARR[@]} | sort -n))`
 echo ${SORTED_NUM_ARR[*]}
 done
```

Output:

```
testb.ksh[118]: -7:  not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort` with process substitution:

```
sort -n <(printf "%s\n" "${NUM_ARR[@]}")
```

Comment: Where you've been till now!.. It's like you saved my life. Though it could had been simplest of the questions... Thanks a million!... I still don't get why `$(printf "%s\n" ${NUM_ARR[@]} | sort -n)` is not working.

Comment: You're most welcome. `printf "%s\n" "${NUM_ARR[@]}" | sort -n` should also work.

Comment: how to assign that properly to a array variable?

Comment: `set -A orderedArray $(printf "%s\n" "${arrayToOrder[@]}" | sort -n | tr "\n" " ");`